Функция ВПР для Postgresql
UPDATE "Мэппинг статья"
SET "Раздел УУ" = "ВПР МЭП_Стат"."J"
FROM "ВПР МЭП_Стат"
WHERE LOWER("ВПР МЭП_Стат"."I") LIKE '%' || LOWER("Мэппинг статья"."Статьи затрат УУ")

Это что-то наподобие ВПР из Excel для SQL. Он работает, но для маленьких массивов данных.
Если увеличить поиск значения на большее количество столбцов и соответственно на большее количество строчек, то обработка занимает продолжительное время. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать код?!

Сколько уникальных значений LOWER("ВПР МЭП_Стат"."I") в процентах от общего числа строк? Если % не большой, можно попробовать создать индекс по вашей функции, однако из-за like он может не использоваться, но попробовать можно.

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Пункты 5 и 3.
